# String to array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

If i have a large string of numbers, is there a way to convert that into an int array? id rather not have to manually code every entry to the array...

small scale example:

```
String s ="12345";
int[] ints = new int[500];
```

how can i end up with:

```
ints[0] = 1;
ints[1] = 2;
ints[2] = 3;
ints[3] = 4;
ints[4] = 5;
```

without manually doing that?

Comment: It decided i wasnt allowed accept straight away and Bozho answerew literally within seconds :P Im also incredibly forgetful so i never remember to come back. Ill make a poin of it from now on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    ints[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: ahh, i was so close... i tried parse int, but it couldnt take the char, never thought of using the ""+s.charAt(i).

ty for quick response

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
      ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(i));
   }
```

Comment: Blah, that is what I call a match! :)

Comment: I improved my answer now anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
String s ="12345";
int[] ints = new int[s.length];
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    ints[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
```

This is much faster than building a StringBuilder/String and parsing it.

Another approach is to use a wrapper instead of creating an array at all

```
public class Ints {
    private final String text;
    public Ints(String text) { this.text = text; }
    public int length() { return text.length(); }
    public int value(int index) { return text.charAt(index) - '0'; }
}

Ints ints = new Ints("12345");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an other alternative:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    ints[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

Comment: What does the `- '0'` mean ?

Comment: I found my answer: 

For any numeric digit you can get the actual value by subtracting out the ascii value of '0'